# Struct with immutable reference to other struct

Tags: rust

First of all I want to apologise for this noob question with an unspecific title, I'm quite new to Rust.

Anyway, here is some (working) code:

```
struct A {
    data: i32
}

struct B<'s> {
    a: &'s A
}

impl<'s> B<'s> {
    fn new(reference: &'s A) -> B<'s> {
        B {
            a: reference
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a1 = A{data: 0};
    let b1 = B::new(&a1);
    let b2 = B::new(&a1);
}
```

There is a struct A with some data and a struct B that contains an immutable reference to A. In the main method several B-objects are created with references to a single A-object.

Now I only want to change one thing: In the B::new() method I want to modify the data of 'reference' before using it as the immutable member of B. I tried it like this:

```
struct A {
    data: i32
}

struct B<'s> {
    a: &'s A
}

impl<'s> B<'s> {
    fn new(reference: &'s mut A) -> B<'s> {

        // Modify data
        reference.data += 1;

        B {
            a: reference
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a1 = A{data: 0};
    let b1 = B::new(&mut a1);
    let b2 = B::new(&mut a1);
}
```

But the compiler won't let me, error: cannot borrow `a1` as mutable more than once at a time. Why isn't the mutable borrow over once new() has finished? What would be the proper way to achieve what I'm trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @AndreaP said, the issue is because of your reference with the same lifetime.

Usually you can work around these issues by simply splitting your functions (one `&` and one `&mut`).

If you really need this kind on pattern, then I think what you are looking for is `Cell`/`RefCell`: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html

EDIT: Thanks to @Ker comment, I updated the code so `B` indeed holds a reference to `A` instead of its copy. Old code was just totally wrong.

```
use std::cell::{Cell};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    data: Cell<i32>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B<'a> {
    a: &'a A
}

impl<'a> B<'a> {
    fn new(reference: &'a A) -> B<'a> {
        // Modify data
        reference.data.set(reference.data.get() + 1);
        B {
            a: reference
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a1 = A{data: Cell::new(0)};
    let b1 = B::new(&a1);
    let b2 = B::new(&a1);
    println!("{}", a1.data.get());
    println!("{:?}", b1);
    println!("{:?}", b2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're totally right and I've modified the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The borrow is not finished because you are keeping that reference alive in `b1`. So the borrow is still alive when you try to do the same for `b2`.

Maybe you just want this:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a1 = A{data: 0};
    let mut a2 = A{data: 0};
    let b1 = B::new(&mut a1);
    let b2 = B::new(&mut a2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I need exactly one A-object to be referenced by several B-objects in my application.